# Flask-SQLAlchemy __bind_key__ not respected for subclasses

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having an issue with model subclasses not respecting the `__bind_key__`. I have a set of models in db1 that use the default binding. I created a second set of models that should reside in db2. The issue I'm having is below. Assuming the classes

```
class Item(db.Model, db.Timestamp):
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'
    __polymorphic__ = 'join'
    item_name = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)

class Sku(Item):
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I can query

```
Item.query.first()
```

and it gets the first item from db2.  The problem is with

```
Sku.query.first()
```

I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table ‘db1.item_sku' doesn't exist")
```

item_sku is in db2, which should be getting queried via the bind key from Item, but it's obviously hitting the default db.  Any ideas?